# CSS float not working properly

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to get a really basic layout using only CSS and divs. What I would like to do is have 3 big divs on the same row and a small div below the first div of the first div in the row. Since I'm trying to set for all of them an height of 400px except for the first one and the small one - which have an heigh of 300px and 100px - I would expect them to show all on the same "line", making a big block. What I get instead is the following:
[image: problem in my layout]

This is my CSS:

```
body    {
    background-color:white;
    }
header    { 
        background-color:black;
        color:red;
        height:10%;
        width:100%;
        padding:1px;
        font-family:verdana;
       }
nav      {  
        background-color:#eeeeee;
        text-align:center;
        height:300px;
        width:10%;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
       }
article {
        height:100px;
        clear:left;
        width:10%;
        background-color:blue;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
section {   
        background-color:yellow;
        height:400px;
        width:50%;
        float:left;
        font-style:italic;
        overflow:hidden;
           }
aside {
        background-color:red;
        float:left;
        width:40%;
        height:400px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
footer {    
        background-color:black;
        padding:5px;
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
        clear:both;
    }
aside img
    {
        max-width:100%; 
        max-height:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        display:block;
    }
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
    <h1 align="center"> Welcome to the official website of Almost Free Furniture</h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <p> <a href="catalog.html">Products</a> </p>
</nav>

<article>
    <p>Hi</p>
</article>

<section>
    <p>Please excuse us while we build our new website.</p>
    <p>In this provisional version you will still able to navigate to our catalogue and see our products.</p>
</section>

<aside id="aside">  
</aside>

<footer>
    This is a work in progress.<br>
    Copyright AlmostFreeFurniture.
</footer>
```

I'm guessing the problem is in the fact that I want the yellow div to float next to two floating divs, and that may be impossible. Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Change `clear:left` to `float:left` for `article`? Not really sure I understand what you like to achive, do you want all divs including the nav to be on the same row?

Comment: @Cyclone Already tried, makes the blue box float right of the gray box, and the yellow box float right of the blue one.
Edit: What I would like to have is all the divs on the same row , with the blue one below the gray one but still to the left of the yellow one

Comment: Remove `float:left` from the gray box and change the style for `article` as I stated above.

Comment: @Cyclone Now the yellow box floats to the right of the blue one, but below the gray box. http://puu.sh/gwrAg/655d633452.jpg

Comment: @Cyclone yes, that's what I'm aiming for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would fix this by wrapping the `nav` and `article` elements in a separate element:

```
.left-column {
  width: 10%;
  float:left;
}
nav {  
  background-color:#eee;
  text-align:center;
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
article {
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

The markup would then become like this:

```
<div class="left-column">
  <nav>
    <p> <a href="catalog.html">Products</a> </p>
  </nav>
  <article>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put a parent around your three elemtns and give it `display: inline-block;`?

Here is a Codepen for an example of a way to solve your problem: [**LINK TO CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYPoGV?editors=110)

Here is some code too if you prefer to look here:

**HTML**

Welcome to the official website of Almost Free Furniture

```
  <div class="inline-div"> <!-- These are the inline-block wrappers -->

    <nav>
        <p> <a href="catalog.html">Products</a> </p>
    </nav>

    <article>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </article>

  </div>

  <div class="inline-div"> <!-- These are the inline-block wrappers -->

    <section>
        <p>Please excuse us while we build our new website.</p>
        <p>In this provisional version you will still able to navigate to our catalogue and see our products.</p>
    </section>

  </div>


  <div class="inline-div"> <!-- These are the inline-block wrappers -->

    <aside id="aside">ANOTHER</aside>

  </div>

<footer>
    This is a work in progress.<br>
    Copyright AlmostFreeFurniture.
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
    header { 
  background-color:black;
  color:red;
  height:10%; width:100%;
  padding:1px;
  font-family:verdana;
}
nav {  
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  text-align:center;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
article { 
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
section {
  background-color:yellow; 
  height:400px;
  font-style:italic;
  overflow:hidden;
           }
aside {
  background-color:red;
  height:400px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
footer {    
  background-color:black;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
}
aside img {
  max-width:100%; max-height:100%;
  margin:0 auto; 
  display:block;
}

.inline-div { display: inline-block; width: 33%; }
```